# React Native - setState doesn't work in promise statement

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and I've been trying to create a login page for an app using a modal. There is a problem, however, whenever I try to remove the modal by using

`this.setState({modalVisable: false})`

Inside a `.then` statement, nothing happens!

When I place the `setState` inside the `.catch` statement, it works and the modal disappears. Why won't it work inside `.then`?

Here's the code:

```
    loginSubmitted(){
    Turbo({site_id: config.TURBO_APP_ID}).fetch('user', {username: this.state.login.username})
    .then((data=>{
        if(data.length==0){
            return Turbo({site_id: config.TURBO_APP_ID}).createUser(this.state.login)
            }else{
            return Turbo({site_id: config.TURBO_APP_ID}).login(this.state.login)
            }
    }))
    .then((data)=>{
        this.setState({modalVisible: false})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        alert(err.message)
        this.setState({modalVisible: false})
    })
}
```

Comment: Add a .bind(this) after your functions

Comment: Where is the code in which  the loginSubmitted function is being called from? Have you put a console log inside your thens to see if they're being called?

Comment: @MattyK14 it is being called from a TouchableOpacity. This is the code:       <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.loginSubmitted()}>
       <Text>
       Go
       </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: @MattyK14 yes, both are being called, I tried console logging and they both work.

Comment: @rory_za Thanks for your reply, I was just wondering which functions I should write .bind(this) after?

Comment: I was thinking after the outer then but it actually looks fine as is. If that was the issue you'd get an error rather than nothing so I'm actually not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @rory_za hmm ok, thanks anyways, thing been bugging me for hours! haha